# sinatra activerecord doesn't find model on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, activerecord, sinatra

I have a classic style sinatra app (not modular), using sinatra-activerecord.

This is my config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require './config/environment'
require './babycomptes' # main application file
run Sinatra::Application
```

and config/environment.rb:

```
APP_ENV = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"
require 'require_all'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default, ENV['SINATRA_ENV'])

require_all 'app'
```

The main app file (babycomptes.rb) is sitting at the root of my project. It contains:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'bcrypt'
require 'securerandom'

require_relative './app/helpers/helpers.rb'
# Dir["./app/models*.rb"].each {|file| require file }

get '/signup' do
    erb :'signup/new'
end

post '/signup' do
    @user = User.new(params[:user]) # this is line 51
    # cut for brievity
end
```

The app works fine when I `rackup` locally and when I run `heroku local`, but runs into an error on heroku :

```
2020-12-30T06:20:27.936954+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-12-30 06:20:27 - NameError - uninitialized constant User:
2020-12-30T06:20:27.936967+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/babycomptes.rb:51:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

no clue where to start looking....

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: yes I did, @Eyeslandic. Ruby 2.7.2 comes with a version of bundler that created some balagan. I downgraded my Ruby version and bundler version and tadaaaa !